# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: on Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I later added a new ForeignKey field to the model. But I encountered such an error. Although I delete this field and delete the database and migrate again, I keep getting this error.

models.py / gayrimenkul

```
class Post(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey('user.User',max_length=120,blank=False,null=False,verbose_name="İlan Sahibi",on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="admin") 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=False,verbose_name="Başlık",help_text="Başlık Giriniz.")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=122,default='',unique=True,null=False,verbose_name='Slug Alanı',editable=False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False,verbose_name="Fiyat")
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name="Detay")
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True,verbose_name='Post Resim',default='',upload_to=upload_to)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The linked model in the ForeignKey field is 'user.User' because I created my own user model.

```
C:\Users\adilc\Desktop\Gayrimenkul\Gmn>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, gayrimenkul, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying gayrimenkul.0001_initial... OK
  Applying gayrimenkul.0002_post_seller...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, 
in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, 
in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 300, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 172, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 239, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 937, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 
790, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 
956, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\adilc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 
965, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'
```

models.py / User

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 30,
    unique=True,
    verbose_name = "Username",
    validators = [RegexValidator(regex = USERNAME_REGEX,
    message="Username must be alphanumeric or contain numbers",
    code="invalid_username")])
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name = "Email",
    )
    registration_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username" 
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        pass

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return self.admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return self.admin
```

Comment: Please write your `User` Model here!

Comment: Maybe you set a wrong default value for something

Comment: @RaminNietzsche i did.

Comment: ok, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070557/valueerror-on-foreignkey-default-value

Comment: A foreign key must be an integer.. you mentioned 'admin' [string].. remove the default value or change it to admin user id number [pk]. Hope this helps!

Comment: @RaminNietzsche I added to_field = 'username' but django still raise same error.
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'

Comment: i deleted migrations folder and did migrate process, it's done, thank you.